# What should be the equilibrium field strength in the Hall effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, electricity

I was taught in my course and have confirmed by looking in many sources that when there are moving charges (e.g. current in a wire) which are deflected due to the Lorentz force (Hall effect), the equilibrium field strength due to the charge separation is : $\mathbf E = q(\mathbf v \times \mathbf B)$, where $\mathbf B$ is the magnetic field strength and $\mathbf v$ the velocity of the charge. 
However, I have read in many sources (most significantly: Purcell's Electricity and Magnetism textbook), that in a charge layer,(for example, on the surface of a conducting sphere) a charge element cannot exert a force on itself, meaning the total force on the layer of charge (and therefore any charge element) is less than you would get by taking the field strength due to all of the charges. 
So my question is, what is the difference between these two scenarios? Why do you not have to consider this difference in the case of the Hall effect? I would reason that equilibrium is reached when every infinitesimal charge element has no force acting on it, but that we should only consider the force due to all the other charge elements. However, if $ d$q is infinitesimal, then removing it will have no effect on the field strength at that point. Which brings me back to the case of the conducting sphere, in which the same argument seemed to me to make sense. So it feels like I am confused about something fundamental, and would really appreciate any clarification!

Comment: what exactly are you confused about? We are ignoring the interaction of that small charge element with itself. But this contribution is going to vanish as we send $dq \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @curio so then how is the case of the conducting sphere different? Why do we get a different force to the total field there?

Comment: we can use the same principle to calcuate the charge distribution (or the force on the charges) on a conducting sphere. why do you think it should be different?

Comment: note that charge elements might be treated differently depending on the situation. If you have a uniformly charged sphere for example you can calculate its potential energy by summing contributions of infinitesimally thin sphere surface elements and you would ignore the interaction of the surface with itself. For calculating the potential energy of a thin layer of charge on a conducting sphere you clearly cannot ignore the forces between the elements on the surface since there isnt any charge elsewhere. In one case we are looking at a volume charge density and in the other a surface density.